# Remove duplicates excel vba

Tags: excel, duplicates, vba

I tried to remove duplicates using below code. But I am not getting desired output. Along with duplicate data other data are also get removed.

```
Sub account()
    Dim d As String
    Call Pvt_Account(192, 8)
End Sub

Sub Pvt_Account(RowNumber As Integer,sheetnumber As Integer)
    Worksheets(sheetnumber).Activate
    NumRows = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count


    m = RowNumber
    CellNumber = 2
    For i = 1 To NumRows - 1
        Sheet2.Range("C" & RowNumber) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("F2:F" & NumRows), Cells(CellNumber, 6)) 

        Sheet2.Range("b" & RowNumber) = Worksheets(sheetnumber).Range("f" & CellNumber)
        RowNumber  = RowNumber + 1
        CellNumber = CellNumber + 1
    Next i

    Worksheets(2).Activate

    r = (m + NumRows) - 2

    Range("B" & m & " :C " & r).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(2), Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

Comment: You are calling `Pvt_Account_Disablement` but your `sub` is named `Pvt_Account`??? Also, what does "not getting the desired result" mean? Please explain what is going wrong explicitly! Also in future make sure to indent your code

Comment: Dan, thanks for the quick response. sub name, i have  given mistakenly, now i have corrected it. But i am facing with the problem in which,  needed data are removed along with duplicate data. I am not getting any syntax error but i think some logical error.

Comment: Your code is not so easy to follow, can I suggest that you add an explanation as to what it's doing (more detailed) and also that you use more expressive variable names. For example, `p` should be called something like `worksheetNumber`. If you also give similarly clear names for `m`, `k`, `j` and `r` your code will be a lot easier for us to read.

Comment: Hi Dan, code have been changed for easy to follow. And this code is a part of my project.I have already mentioned , What problem I am facing on this code. Suggest a solution for this. Thank You

Comment: I'm sorry but if you're not going to explain what your code does (i.e. what you think each loop in there is trying to achieve etc, not just the overall goal) and you're not properly explaining what goes wrong with examples (I suggest before and after screenshots of short columns of data), then your question is simply incomplete.

Comment: I got the solution for my problem. Thanks Dan for considering my problem.

Answer (score 1):

In

```
Range("B" & m & " :C " & r).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(2), Header:=xlYes
```

, I think you will want `Columns:=Array(1)` instead, i.e. removing duplicates from the first column of the range `Bm:Cr`, which is `B`. The space after `:C` should also be removed.

Comment: Kim Phú Ngô, thanks a lot for your solution. It works now and thank you Dan for your quick response.